# Identify the difference in column in a specific row for a particular key column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables in SQL Server, `table1` and `table2`. Both have the same schema and equal number of rows. I am trying to find if there is any difference in any column value for particular rows.

I did with `Except` to find the difference, but there is millions of rows, so trying to customize.

Code:

```
select * from T1
except
select * from T2
```

But the above code does not return the correct result.

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(
    KEYCOL VARCHAR(60),
    COL2 CHAR(20),
    COL3 INT,
    COL4 VARCHAR(30)
)

INSERT INTO T1
    SELECT 1000004177   R09 1   909622  UNION ALL
    SELECT 1000004478   Q22 1   3659573 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1000008983   Q16 1   955987  UNION ALL
    SELECT 1000010178   XX1 1   3069968 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1000013347   R09 1   3679779 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1000014510   Q16 1   YYY23   UNION ALL
    SELECT 1000015230   R17 1   1000015230 UNION ALL    
    SELECT 1000016049   Q16 1   1000016049 UNION ALL    
    SELECT 1000016332   Q16 1   1000016332

CREATE TABLE T2
(
    KEYCOL VARCHAR(60),
    COL2 CHAR(20),
    COL3 INT,
    COL4 VARCHAR(30)
)

INSERT INTO T2
    SELECT 1000004177   R09 1   909622  UNION ALL
    SELECT 1000004478   Q22 1   3659573 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1000008983   Q16 1   955987  UNION ALL
    SELECT 1000010178   ZZZ 1   3069968 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1000013347   R09 1   3679779 UNION ALL
    SELECT 1000014510   Q16 1   ZZZ23   UNION ALL
    SELECT 1000015230   R17 1   1000015230 UNION ALL    
    SELECT 1000016049   Q16 1   1000016049 UNION ALL    
    SELECT 1000016332   Q16 1   1000016332
```

Desired output:

```
1000004177  NO CHANGE
1000004478  NO CHANGE
1000008983  NO CHANGE
1000010178  CHANGE IN COL2
1000013347  NO CHANGE
1000014510  CHANGE IN COL4
1000015230  NO CHANGE
1000016049  NO CHANGE
1000016332  NO CHANGE
```

May you please share yours thoughts.

Comment: What is your question ? Where is your Query with Except

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `join` and some conditional logic.  Something like this:

```
select t1.keycol,
       stuff( (case when t1.col2 <> t2.col2 then ', CHANGE IN COL2' else '' end) +
              (case when t1.col3 <> t2.col3 then ', CHANGE IN COL3' else '' end) +
              (case when t1.col4 <> t2.col4 then ', CHANGE IN COL4' else '' end)
              1, 2, '')
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.keycol = t2.keycol;
```

This version produces `''` when the columns are all the same rather than `'NO CHANGE'`.

Comment: @TULSI . . . So write more than 25 expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table with Primary Key and hash of all columns in the table.
Few samples are here:
[SQL way to get the MD5 or SHA1 of an entire row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16452658/sql-way-to-get-the-md5-or-sha1-of-an-entire-row)
Insert keys and hashes from both source tables into the hash table.

After creating such table you can run:

```
SELECT PrimaryKey,Hash
FROM HashTable 
GROUP BY PrimaryKey,Hash
HAVING COUNT(1) = 1
```

This query will identify different rows.
There is always a possibility of hash collisions, but probability is so low that you may ignore it.